# Access violation for object

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, pointers, ogre

I have an Entity.h like this:

using namespace physx;

```
class Entity
{

public:
    Entity(Ogre::Vector3 dims, Ogre::Vector3 pos, std::string mesh, std::string id);
    virtual ~Entity(void);
    virtual void update(Ogre::Real dt);
    virtual void init(Ogre::SceneManager* sceneMgr, PxPhysics* physics, PxScene* scene, PxVec3 velocity=PxVec3(0, 0, 0));
protected:
    Ogre::Entity*       mOgreEntity = NULL;
    Ogre::SceneNode*    mOgreNode = NULL;

    Ogre::Vector3       mPosition;
    Ogre::Vector3       mDimensions;
    std::string         mMesh;
    std::string         mId;


    PxRigidDynamic*     mActor;
    PxMaterial*         mMaterial;
};
```

And here is my Entity source:

```
#include "Entity.h"

Entity::Entity(Ogre::Vector3 dims, Ogre::Vector3 pos, std::string mesh, std::string id) 
{

    mDimensions = dims;
    mPosition   = pos;
    mMesh       = mesh;
    mId         = id;
    mActor      = NULL;
    mMaterial   = NULL;
}

Entity::~Entity(void)
{

}

void Entity::update(Ogre::Real dt)
{
    PxVec3 pos = mActor->getGlobalPose().p;
    Ogre::Real r = 0;
    mOgreNode->setPosition(Ogre::Vector3(pos.x + r, pos.y + r, pos.z + r));
}

void Entity::init(Ogre::SceneManager* sceneMgr, PxPhysics* physics, PxScene* scene, PxVec3 velocity)
{
    // Create an Entity
    mOgreEntity = sceneMgr->createEntity(mId, mMesh);
    mOgreEntity->setCastShadows(true);

    // Create a SceneNode and attach the Entity to it
    mOgreNode = sceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode(mId + "Node");
    Ogre::AxisAlignedBox box = mOgreEntity->getBoundingBox();
    Ogre::Vector3 realSizes = box.getSize();

    mOgreNode->setPosition(mPosition);
    mOgreNode->attachObject(mOgreEntity);

    Ogre::Vector3 scaler = Ogre::Vector3(mDimensions.x / realSizes.x, mDimensions.y / realSizes.y, mDimensions.z / realSizes.z);
    mOgreNode->scale(scaler);


    mMaterial = physics->createMaterial(1.5f, 1.5f, 1.0f);
    PxGeometry* geometry = NULL;
    if(mMesh == "sphere.mesh")
    {
        PxGeometry g = PxSphereGeometry(mDimensions.x / 2); // Because it's a radius
        geometry = &g;
    } else {
        // geometry = NULL;
    }
    PxTransform transform = PxTransform(PxVec3(mPosition.x, mPosition.y, mPosition.z));
    mActor = PxCreateDynamic(*physics, transform, *geometry, *mMaterial, PxReal(.1));
    // if(!mActor) {
 //        MessageBox( NULL, "no actor", "An exception has occured!", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR | MB_TASKMODAL);
    //  return;
    // }
    mActor->setLinearVelocity(velocity);
    // And add the actor to a scene:

    scene->addActor(*mActor);

}
```

Now, if I create a single entity and initialize it works. Even wirh a second entity var it works as well. Now with an array:

```
Entity *mEntities[20];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++ ){
    ostringstream nameStream;
    nameStream << "Sphere_" << i;
    string name = nameStream.str();
    Entity* sphere = new Entity(Ogre::Vector3(i*5, i*4.5, i*6), Ogre::Vector3(i*5, i*4.5, i*6), "sphere.mesh", name);
    sphere->init(mSceneMgr, mPhysics, gScene, PxVec3(-10.0f, 0, 0));
    mEntities[i] = sphere;

}
```

I got `Access violation`. W/ the just-in-time debugger, it turned out that `mActor`was null as well as `mMaterial`

**EDIT:**

This code does not work either:

```
    mEntity = Entity(Ogre::Vector3(50.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f), Ogre::Vector3(50.0f, 40.5f, 60.0f), "sphere.mesh", "sphere");
    mEntity.init(mSceneMgr, mPhysics, gScene, PxVec3(-10.0f, 0, 0));
```

Comment: I would suggest you initialize your pointers to NULL in the constructor of `Entity`.  Your code also does absolutely no error checking to see if those functions you're calling actually return good values.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for your suggestion but I edited the source and I still get this error :/. See updated post

Comment: `geometry = &PxSphereGeometry(mDimensions.x / 2);` Please explain what this line is supposed to do. Anyone looking at it would think that you're assigning the address of a temporary, which will be absolutely no good after that statement is completed.

Comment: Err, I'm creating a geometry var which contains the geometry to be used by PxCreateDynamics. Is it wrong? Why?

Comment: Explain again, but use C++ terms.  Are you assigning to `geometry` the address of a temporary?  If you are, then that is no good.

Comment: Srry I'm a beginner. By temp, do you mean I will only use it once?  If yes then yes

Comment: No, by temporary, it means that an object is created, is returned, and then goes away in a puff of smoke.  So you're assigning the address of something that will not be there after that line is executed.

Comment: And how do I know that? Is it because of the &?

Comment: A function returns something to you.  You either copy or assign that something to a variable, or you let whatever is returned to you die off because you don't care about the return value.  But you *never* take the address of a returned function call.  On the same not, why is `geometry` a pointer?

Comment: Oh thank you I can clearly see it now. Is better now? I've updated the post

Comment: That still isn't correct according to the docs here:  http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/apireference/files/classPxSphereGeometry.html  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**1)**

```
Entity* sphere = new Entity(Ogre::Vector3(i*5, i*4.5, i*6), 
                            Ogre::Vector3(i*5, i*4.5, i*6), 
                            "sphere.mesh", 
                            "Sphere_"+i);
```

Look at the `"Sphere_"+i`
If the `i` is larger then length of ”Sphere_” you are passing pointer to some random memory. I assume that you wanted to create a string with i at the end. 
Use `sprintf` or `std::string` for that.

**2)**
If you change the loop range from 20 to let's say 3 it will probably work. The problem is that your names will be: 
Sphere_, phere_, here_
Because by doing `"Sphere_"+i` you are not adding integer to the string. 
This is "equal" to:

```
char *string = "String";
string += 3;
```

**3)** 
This code will generate string that you need:

```
std::ostringstream newStringStream;
newStringStream << "Sphere_" << i;
std::string newString = newStringStream.str();
```

Comment: Thanks for the string, it did not resolved the access viollation but it resolved another

Comment: In which line and which iteration you get a crash ?
Edit: Sorry didn't read the code properly nvm.

Comment: On line `mActor->setLinearVelocity(velocity);` at first iteration

Answer (score 1):

Here is another issue:

```
PxGeometry* geometry = NULL;
if(mMesh == "sphere.mesh")
{
    geometry = &PxSphereGeometry(mDimensions.x / 2); // Because it's a radius
}
```

The problem with this is that you are assigning to `geometry` the address of a temporary value.  Once that line of code is completed, that temporary is gone.

The probable fix for this is to do this:

```
PxGeometry geometry;
if(mMesh == "sphere.mesh")
{
    geometry = PxSphereGeometry(mDimensions.x / 2); // Because it's a radius
}
//...
mActor = PxCreateDynamic(*physics, transform, geometry, *mMaterial, PxReal(.1));
```

Now `geometry` is no longer a pointer, and you're assigning geometry to the value returned, (not address-of the value returned).

I am reading the documentation here:

http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/apireference/files/classPxSphereGeometry.html

So `PxSphereGeometry(x)` is a constructor call.  So you need to assign the return `value` to a `PxShpereGeometry`, not a `PxSphereGeometry*`.

Edit:  Your latest changes also do not have the desired effect:

```
 if(mMesh == "sphere.mesh")
 {
     PxGeometry g = PxSphereGeometry(mDimensions.x / 2); // Because it's a radius
     geometry = &g;
  }
```

The `g` is local to the `if()` block.  You assign the address of this `g` to `geometry`.  Then when that block exits, `g` is gone, and now you have `geometry` pointing to something that no longer exists.

The difference between your edited code and the answer I gave is that my answer `assigns` the return value to an existing object.  So I created a duplicate of the return value.  What your doing in the edited code is not creating a duplicate, but pointing to a local object, which as explained, won't exist after it leaves scope.

So if you were to write code that follows the pattern of your edited code, and have it be valid, the change would look like this:

```
 PxGeometry geometry; 
 if(mMesh == "sphere.mesh")
 {
     PxGeometry g = PxSphereGeometry(mDimensions.x / 2); // Because it's a radius
     geometry = g;  
 }
```

However, this does extraneous work.  The original answer is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, but the PxGeometry has no default constructor, that's why  used a pointer to use NULL

Comment: @Vinz243 - An object is created, it is a temporary, and you cannot assign a pointer to a temporary and expect that pointer to be pointing to anything valid once the temporary goes away (which will occur when that statement ends). I don't know how more simpler I can explain it.

Comment: OK I changed the line from `PxGeometry geometry;` to `PxGeometry geometry = PxSphereGeometry();`, it compiles, but I still get that access violation error

Comment: Please change it to *exactly* as I posted in the answer.  What you just posted is not correct either if you placed that statement inside of the `if (mMesh...` block.  The reason why it isn't correct is because now, `geometry` is temporary and will go away when that `if()` block completes.

Comment: @Vinz243 - Just saw your changes. Still wrong, as per my previous comment. You need to learn the basics of `object lifetimes` and `block scope`. You declared `g` locally inside of the `if()` block. It's going away as soon as that block exits.

Comment: Thanks, i know what scope are since they are also present in JavaScript, but I'll check some books about lifetime. But the object in your example is a PxGeometry which doesn't have a constructor so the compiler won't do his job :'(

Comment: And I've just realised, didn't I made the same mistake in the for loop? If so how am i supposed to make an array of pointers?

Comment: @Vinz243 You are wrong.  Every object has a constructor.  If you don't provide one, the compiler provides a no argument constructor.  As to the loop, no, it is not the same thing as you were doing befoe.  You are creating objects dynamically using `new`, therefore they exist until you call `delete`.  Having said that, it would be better if you created an array of smart pointers, since if you don't call `delete` for all of those pointer values, you get memory leaks.

Comment: @Vinz243 - You seem to be missing some basic fundamentals of C++.  It will be difficult to avoid these IMO simple errors if you use C++ by  "winging it".  The problem is that unlike other languages, where if the code compiles, almost all the time the program just "works", the  same cannot be said of C++.  You can compile code that looks ok, but be totally full of holes and mistakes.  Compound that with not learning the language in a formal manner, and you have a disaster on your hands.

Comment: I understand that and that's why I'm stating with simple examples before diving into my final project, I believe that the best way to learn a new language is actually practicing it. I did it for javascript (I already knew java), and I had to rewrite my code twice but at the end I felt confortable in js.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the alternate way to create a rigid body and it worked!!!!

```
mActor = physics->createRigidDynamic(PxTransform(PxVec3(mPosition.x, mPosition.y, mPosition.z)));
PxShape* shape = mActor->createShape(PxSphereGeometry(mDimensions.x / 2), *mMaterial);
PxRigidBodyExt::updateMassAndInertia(*mActor, 0.4f);
```